# PHP Filtering MySQL Statement

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to get my page to filter through a database and display results in a table. Currently there is a form in the **competitorFilter2.php** and **competitorFilterResults2.php** should display the filtered competitors, however it just displays a blank table. I am not really concerned about the correctness of the code or it being open to SQL injections at this stage. I just need it to work first. Code below. Thanks in advance.

**competitorFilter2.php**

```
        <div>

            <h4>Filter Competitors:</h4>

            <div class="form-group">

            <label class="col-md-2" for="" required>Gender:</label>

            <div class="col-md-10">

            <label><input type="radio" class="form-control" name="male" value="male">Male</label><br>

            <label><input type="radio" class="form-control" name="female" value="female">Female</label>

            </div>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">

            <label class="col-md-2" required>Age:</label>

            <div class="col-md-10">



                <label><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="age4" value="4">4</label><br>

                <label><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="age5" value="5">5</label><br>

                <label><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="age6" value="6">6</label><br>

                <label><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="age7" value="7">7</label><br>

                <label><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="age8" value="8">8</label><br>

                <label><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="age9" value="9">9</label><br>

                <label><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="age10" value="10">10</label><br>

                <label><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="age11" value="11">11</label><br>

                <label><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="age12" value="12">12</label><br>

                <label><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="age13" value="13">13</label><br>

                <label><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="age14" value="14">14</label><br>

                <label><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="age15" value="15">15</label><br>

                <label><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="age16" value="16">16</label><br>

                <label><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="age17" value="17">17</label><br>



            </div>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">

                <label class="col-md-2" required>Grade/Belt:</label>

                <div class="col-md-10">



                <label><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="beltB" value="Beginner">Beginner</label><br>

                <label><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="belt9" value="9th Kyu White Belt">9th Kyu White Belt</label><br>

                <label><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="belt8" value="8th Kyu Yellow Belt">8th Kyu Yellow Belt</label><br>

                <label><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="belt7" value="7th Kyu Orange Belt">7th Kyu Orange Belt</label><br>

                <label><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="belt6" value="6th Kyu Green Belt">6th Kyu Green Belt</label><br>

                <label><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="belt5" value="5th Kyu Blue Belt">5th Kyu Blue Belt</label><br>

                <label><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="belt4" value="4th Kyu Purple Belt">4th Kyu Purple Belt</label><br>

                <label><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="belt3" value="3rd Kyu Brown Belt">3rd Kyu Brown Belt</label><br>

                <label><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="belt2" value="2nd Kyu Brown Belt">2nd Kyu Brown Belt</label><br>

                <label><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="belt1" value="1st Kyu Brown Belt">1st Kyu Brown Belt</label><br>

                <label><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="belt1BB" value="1st Dan Black Belt">1st Dan Black Belt</label><br>

                <label><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="belt2BB" value="2nd Dan Black Belt">2nd Dan Black Belt</label><br>



                </div>

            </div>

                <div class="form-group">

                    <label class="col-md-2" for="" require>Event:</label>

                    <div class="col-md-10">

                            <label><input type="radio" class="form-control" name="beginnerroutine" value="beginnerroutine">Beginner Routine</label><br>

                            <label><input type="radio" class="form-control" name="kata" value="kata">Kata</label><br>

                            <label><input type="radio" class="form-control" name="kumite" value="kumite">Kumite</label><br>

                            <label><input type="radio" class="form-control" name="openkumite" value="openkumite">Open Kumite</label>

                    </div>

                </div>
                <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
```

**competitorFilterResults2.php**

```
           <table id="myTable">
                <tr class="header">
                    <th style="width:25%;">Last Name/First Name</td>                       
                    <th style="width:25%;">Age</td>                                              
                    <th style="width:25%;">Grade</td>
                    <th style="width:25%;">Club</td>
                </tr>

           <?php               
               $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "afmaclub_admin", "EliteYouth2018", "afmaclub_Competitors");


                if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
                    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
                    exit();
                }



                /*Create table doesn't return a resultset*/ 
                if ($mysqli->query("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE afmaclub_Competitors LIKE AFMAClubCompetition") === TRUE) {
                    printf("Table Competitors successfully created.\n");
                }

                $male = $_POST['male'];
                $female = $_POST['female'];
                $beginnerroutine = $_POST['beginnerroutine'];
                $kata = $_POST['kata'];
                $kumite = $_POST['kumite'];
                $openkumite = $_POST['openkumite'];
                $age4 = $_POST['age4'];
                $age5 = $_POST['age5'];
                $age6 = $_POST['age6'];
                $age7 = $_POST['age7'];
                $age8 = $_POST['age8'];
                $age9 = $_POST['age9'];
                $age10 = $_POST['age10'];
                $age11 = $_POST['age11'];
                $age12 = $_POST['age12'];
                $age13 = $_POST['age13'];
                $age14 = $_POST['age14'];
                $age15 = $_POST['age15'];
                $age16 = $_POST['age16'];
                $age17 = $_POST['age17'];
                $beltB = $_POST['beltB'];
                $belt9 = $_POST['belt9'];
                $belt8 = $_POST['belt8'];
                $belt7 = $_POST['belt7'];
                $belt6 = $_POST['belt6'];
                $belt5 = $_POST['belt5'];
                $belt4 = $_POST['belt4'];
                $belt3 = $_POST['belt3'];
                $belt2 = $_POST['belt2'];
                $belt1 = $_POST['belt1'];
                $belt1BB = $_POST['belt1BB'];
                $belt2BB = $_POST['belt2BB'];

                $sql = "
SELECT firstname
     , lastname
     , age
     , belt
     , club 
  FROM AFMAClubCompetition 
 WHERE (male = '".$male."' OR female = '".$female."') 
   AND (beginnerroutine = '".$beginnerroutine."' OR kata = '".$kata."' OR kumite = '".$kumite."' OR openkumite = '".$openkumite."') 
   AND (age = $age4, $age5, $age6, $age6, $age7, $age8, $age9, $age10, $age11, $age12, $age13, $age14, $age15, $age16, $age17) 
   AND (belt = $beltB, $belt9, $belt8, $belt7, $belt6, $belt5, $belt4, $belt3, $belt2, $belt1, $belt1BB, $belt2BB)
";                 

        return $sql;

                $results = $mysqli->query($sql);
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {

            ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $row['lastname']?> <?php echo $row['firstname']?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['age']?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['belt']?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['club']?></td>
                    </tr>

                <?php
                }

                mysqli_close($results);

                ?>
             </table>
```

Comment: '*I am not really concerned about the correctness of the code or it being open to SQL injections at this stage. I just need it to work first.*' - No, but you should be. Generally what tends to happen is that people say that they'll fix it insecure code "after" the feature is working however, "after" never comes.

Comment: ...plus, when you refactor the code, you will most likely end up with other issues, sending you right back here again. Why not save both you and us some time instead of debugging code you will need to throw away right after you get it working?

Comment: `AND (age = $age4, $age5...` Replace = with IN,first thing that jumped to me

Comment: try `die($mysqli->error)` after `$results = $mysqli->query($sql);` to see if sql has no issue.

Comment: Btw, using Prepared Statements doesn't just help you against deliberate attacks, it also helps you in other ways. Ex. if any value currently happens to contain a single quote `'`, your query will fail.

Comment: This seems like a rather clumsy form, which is leading to a very clumsy query against (what is hopefully) a thoughtfully designed table.

Answer (score 0):

```
$results = $mysqli->query($sql);
           echo("<table>");
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {

      echo "
                <tr>
                    <td>".echo $row['lastname']." ".echo $row['firstname']."</td>
                    <td>".echo $row['age']."</td>
                    <td>".echo $row['belt']."</td>
                    <td>".echo $row['club']."</td>
                </tr>";


            }

            echo("</table>");
```

you can use this method by using this method table row auto generating

Comment: Thanks for this but I don't think that's the problem as I have other pages with hard coded SQL statements and the same method of table row generation and they work fine. Thanks though